# I need https::/mysite.com instead of https::/mysite.com/wordpress

Tags: errors

Now my site is like https::/mysite.com/wordpress
If I go to https::/mysite.com I get 403 Forbidden
How to fix that?

Comment: Have you installed your WP in subdirectory or directly in domain root?

Comment: It is installed as htdocs/www/wordpress

Comment: So that’s the reason - you’ve installed WP in subdirectory, so it is exactly there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of such behavior is that you’ve installed your WP in `/wordpress` subdirectory, so that’s exactly where it works. And since the root directory is empty (no index.php nor .htaccess files are in there) you get 403 error, when requesting domain root.

**So how to fix it?**

1. Connect to your ftp server and move files from subdirectory to domain root. So all files from `/WordPress` subdirectory should be moved to its parent directory. When `wordpress` directory is empty, remove it.
2. Edit `.htaccess` file and remove `wordpress` part in rewrite rules.
3. Change all paths/URLs in database. You can use this tool to do it: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is adding these into your wp-config.php as a first step to make sure that they are correctly set always.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Chances are if that doesn't fix it you have something like this in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress [L]
```

Then if your still 403, start working your way down one of the many lists of possible reasons you are getting a 403
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: Ouch downvoted because I gave the correct answer before anyone was made aware the whole site was installed in a subfolder, kinda cold blooded I would harly call my information unhelpful as it would be the answer to the other 50% of the times this issue comes about